# hello.py to hello.exe conversion in python 3.6

Tags: python, cx-freeze, python-3.6

I have created a hello.py, which will print hello world 10 times with delay of 1 sec each.

```
import time
for i in range(0,10):
   print("hello")
   time.sleep(1)
```

Now when I convert this to exe using cx_Freeze method, hello.exe is created and it is not running. I'am running this on Windows 7 64 bit PC.

Comment: Is that an exact copy of your code cause if so it has some syntax errors

Comment: code is not a problem .

Comment: Really cause when I type Print("hello") I get an error saying that "Print" is not defined.

Comment: when i run the same code as hello.py it works

Comment: my question is i want to convert .py yo .exe in python 3.6

Comment: There is absolutely no way that code will execute in Python with the capitalised keywords. `Import`, `For`, `Print`, `Sleep`...

Comment: Now i edited my code

Comment: my question is how to convert .py to .exe

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/). It takes python code and converts it into an executable. It might be overkill for what you're doing but it's worth a shot if the method you're currently using doesn't work. Check out the options you can run it with to make it a standalone executable.

Comment: pyinstaller supports 3.6 ??

Comment: I didn't realize you were using 3.6... as far as I know pyinstaller does not support python 3.6. You could try [py2exe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/0.9.2.0) instead. According to that link it works on python 3.3 and up. It should function similarly to pyinstaller.

Comment: i am geeting this error ImportError: No module named __startup__

Answer (score 0):

You can try script at:

https://github.com/soimort/you-get/wiki/cx_Freeze

Replace `you-get` with your `hello.py`